# Flutter App Running Error: Dart can not be opened, Developer can not be verified after upgrading to Catalina

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, macos-catalina

I was using the latest version of `Android Studio IDE` for creating `flutter` apps. But when I upgraded from Mojave to Catalina and tried to open my `flutter` code on IDE it gave me an error saying:

> Dart can not be opened because the Developer can not be verified

What is the reason behind the error and how can I solve the issue?

Do I have to install flutter and relative development tools from scratch again or is there any other way to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: In my case I've solved it by deleting `cache` dir located at `flutter/bin` folder.

Answer (score 126):

Do this steps and repeat until allow all you need and stop notifications.
Solve for me.

1. On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click
   Security & Privacy, then click General.
2. Click the lock icon  to unlock it, then enter an administrator
   name and password.
3. Select the sources from which you’ll allow software to be
   installed: There should be a button that says "Allow anyway". If not
   make sure you've cancelled the error dialog.

Comment: "3-Select the sources from which you’ll allow software to be installed" -- there should be a button that says "Allow anyway". If not make sure you've cancelled the error dialog.

Answer (score 27):

*usually you will not be allowed to install the applications dowloaded form other sources .... you need to first give permissions in the system Preferences*

1. apple-icon on left top corner > System Preferences > click Security & Privacy > then click General... now Click the lock icon to unlock it ...
   2.now, you will be shown with below attached image ... click allow anyway ..
   [image]
2. now retry installing ... you are good to go...

Answer (score 7):

You can run this command to allow your mac/apps downloaded from anywhere

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend disabling Gatekeeper unless you are fully aware of the risk.

Answer (score 7):

Disabling entire Gate Keeper is definitely not a good idea as it will result running any type of program on your system.

You can add Dart to the white list by running this in terminal:

```
sudo spctl --add "Path_to_flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart"
```

You might require to reboot the system in order to apply the changes.

There are several other binaries other than Dart that may get blocked as well.

**You can run GateKeeper script to fix the issue:**

https://github.com/AmirKamali/Flutter_GateKeeper_Fix

**I have published an article with more information how to fix this:**

https://medium.com/@amir.n3t/how-to-fix-flutter-idevice-id-running-errors-in-mac-osx-catalina-7aa1f89f61aa

Answer (score 4):

So who the hell is an "identified developer" if Google chooses not to be one? Something is wrong with this

Answer (score 4):

i updated mac to Big sur and then got this problem.

Allowing dart in the security and privacy settings and then Deleting ...flutter/bin/cache folder solved it for me.

run `flutter doctor` in terminal afterwards to reinstall dart SDK

Comment: Thanks Efhem. This totally worked for me

Comment: Thank you! Deleting the cache folder solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

## 2022 update

The button is now at

 → System Settings → Privacy & Security → Scroll down to **Security** → `Allow anyway`

[image: Allow button]

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be resolved by deleting the `artefacts` directory and running `flutter doctor` once again - [More Info Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42969#issuecomment-568303471)